# Query Wikidata REST API with related identifier

Tags: wikidata-api

I am attempting to do alignments for a set of known VIAF IDs. I would like to query the Wikidata REST API with a VIAF ID (P214) and get back a set of one or more Wikidata entity IDs (QXXXXX) that correspond to that VIAF entity. I am unable to find any examples of this either in the Wikidata API documentation or otherwise online.

I've noodled around with various permutations of queries using `action=wbsearchentities` and `action=query`, all to no avail.

Could anyone kindly point me to set of docs or example code that enumerates the correct query parameters for such a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to find the item whose VIAF ID is "113230702" (i.e. [Douglas Adams](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42)).

#### Solution 1

Use `action=query`:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=haswbstatement:P214=113230702
```

URL response:

```json
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"searchinfo":{"totalhits":1},"search":[{"ns":0,"title":"Q42","pageid":138,"size":319024,"wordcount":1204,"snippet":"Douglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\n\u0414\u0443\u0433\u043b\u0430\u0441 \u0410\u0434\u0430\u043c\u0441\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams\nDouglas Adams","timestamp":"2021-08-13T22:04:39Z"}]}}
```

#### Solution 2

Use [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/):

```
https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fx%0AWHERE%20{%0A%20%20%3Fx%20wdt%3AP214%20%22113230702%22%0A}
```

This last URL comes from the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x
WHERE {
  ?x wdt:P214 "113230702"
}
```

URL response:

```json
{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "x" ]
  },
  "results" : {
    "bindings" : [ {
      "x" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q42"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Please, consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried, but it said I need "experience" of at least 15, which apparently I lack. Or do you mean something else?